# optimize image acquisition opencv

Tags: c++, opencv, video-capture

I am currently doing a software that needs to take photos of the changes in a fluid when heat is applied. I have to take the photos every 100 ms. I did a "hello world" code to check if it was possible where it just takes the photo without synchronization

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc.hpp"
#include "opencv2/highgui.hpp"
#include<time.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

using namespace std;
using namespace cv;


//** @function main */
int main()
{
    //! [mat]
    int n=5;
    Mat * frame;
    frame = new Mat[n];
    //! [mat]
    //! [cap]
    VideoCapture cap(0);
    //! [cap]
    //! [window]
    time_t prev = clock();
    namedWindow("video capture", WINDOW_NORMAL);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 4008);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 3700);
    cap.set(CV_CAP_PROP_EXPOSURE, -2.5);
    //! [window]
    //! [trackbar]

    //while ((char)waitKey(1) != 'q') {
    for (int i = 0; i<5; i++) {
        cout << clock()-prev<<endl;
        prev = clock();
        //! [while]
        cap >> frame[i];

        //! [show]
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) 
        imwrite("test" + std::to_string(i) + ".jpg", frame[i]);
    while ((char)waitKey(1) != 'q') {}
    return 0;
}
```

I started saving the images as soon as took them and I got an elapsed time of 600 ms approximately. therefore I stored them in a dynamic array. this lowered times in half but still not what I need. I am using visual studio 2017 community this is the release code using opencv 3.3.1 the camera is a lumenera and images taken are 4008x3700 px. the commented code was used to visualize the images in a 1080p display but I disabled it since I don't need to see every frame in this stage

Comment: This is a bit unclear, but note that your code is undefined due to the lack of initialisation of `n`.

Comment: Side note: remove irrelevant code, don't comment it out. Post the code you're measuring along with your measurements.

Comment: I changed it, and adding the measurements are not really the point here since there is a lot of code involved for that I just need to make that section of code faster just the image captuire